# Refinitiv-Eikon python API returns 404 | client error

Tags: python, refinitiv-eikon-api, refinitiv-eikon

I have been trying to make a python script that get's data from Refinitiv-Eikon but i keep getting a 404. It looks like the page it tries to reach does not exist. But there is nothing i seem to do wrong. I use the wealth management version of Eikon:

```
2023-09-01 14:53:21,970 P[107992] [MainThread 98960] Error code 404 | Client Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /api/v1/data</pre>
</body>
</html>

2023-09-01 14:53:21,972 P[107992] [MainThread 98960] HTTP request failed: EikonError-Client Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /api/v1/data</pre>
</body>
</html>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\eikon\json_requests.py", line 127, in send_json_request
    _raise_for_status(response)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\eikon\json_requests.py", line 271, in _raise_for_status
    raise EikonError(response.status_code, error_msg)
eikon.eikonError.EikonError: Error code 404 | Client Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /api/v1/data</pre>
</body>
</html>


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\niekm\Dropbox\Personal\Coding\python\Django\stockManager\stockmanager\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    df, err = ek.get_news_headlines('R:LHAG.DE', date_from='2019-03-06T09:00:00', date_to='2019-03-06T18:00:00')#ek.get_data(instruments=[symbol], fields=fields)
  File "C:\Users\niekm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\eikon\news_request.py", line 121, in get_news_headlines
    result = eikon.json_requests.send_json_request(News_Headlines_UDF_endpoint, payload, debug=debug)
  File "C:\Users\niekm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\eikon\json_requests.py", line 134, in send_json_request
    raise EikonError(eikon_err.code, eikon_err.message)
eikon.eikonError.EikonError: Error code 404 | Client Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /api/v1/data</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code that I got from their website... I saw it used to work through a proxy but that no longer exists:

```
import eikon as ek


ek.set_app_key("XXX")

# Make API request
df, err = ek.get_news_headlines('R:LHAG.DE', date_from='2019-03-06T09:00:00', date_to='2019-03-06T18:00:00')

if err: print("Error:", err)
else: print("Data:", df)
```

It should return the headlines of LHAG.DE

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good maybe try changing the date range. It might 2019 there is no news for the given company. I tried at my end and it worked.

Comment: It did not seem to work, it might be because of the version I am using. But, I stopped testing since they will remove my version of eikon somewhere next year.